# How to use a local loop variable outside?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
data = soup.find('div', class_='llist') # Tags
for loop in data.findAll('a', href=True):
    var1 = loop.text
    print(var1)
```

Above code prints out all lines of the soup extraction, however I need to use the variable `var1` outside of the loop, and have no idea how. When I try and print `var1` outside the loop it only prints the last line of the data.

Above code prints:

```
Apples
Tomatoes
Grapes
Sausage
Corn
```

If i use var outside the loop it only prints `Corn`.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I went through a lot of similar questions and either can't find or can't understand the answers.

Comment: *"When I try and print "var1" outside the loop it only prints the last line of the data."* Because that's exactly what it should be doing. You are setting `var1 ` to `loop.text` at the end of the loops iteration. As such it will be the last element because that's what it was when the loop ended.

Comment: Ok, how would I go about getting all the text and not just the last line?

Comment: Append all the var1s in a list and access the list outside

Comment: Thanks, I tried appending it to a list earlier but did was appending it outside the actual loop. Woops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the vars in a list while iterating

```
data = soup.find('div', class_='llist') # Tags
my_vars = []
for loop in data.findAll('a', href=True):
    my_vars.append(loop.text)

print my_vars 
# ["Apples", "Tomatoes", "Grapes", "Sausage", "Corn"]
```

Comment: `my_vars = [loop.text for loop in data.findAll('a', href=True)]`